# Запуск скриптов python в debian после обновления системы

Tags: python, debian

Обновил систему пару дней назад. Проблема в следующем:
новые скрипты python при вызове пытаются обрабатываться в bash, хотя везде стоит shebang line:

`#!/usr/bin/env python3`

При этом если запустить как:

python scriptname.py

все хорошо. Ранее созданные скрипты продолжают работать. Пробовал копировать шебанг из старых скриптов в новые, не помогло. И старые и новые находятся скрипты в одной директории. В чем может быть проблема? Спасибо.

Comment: А если запускать так, всё ок?
python3  scriptname.py

Comment: а питон3 установлен?

Comment: Да, python3 установлен. Если запускать как python3 scriptname.py все ок.

Comment: Решил вопрос переустановкой питона. Проблема исчезла. Но не уверен, что топор лучшее лекарство от головной боли.